# PHP DateTime issue

Tags: php, datetime

I've run into something unusual. For some reason when adding a dateinterval with only minutes set in it makes it add 67 years.

```
$wTime = new DateTime("2011-05-17 01:54:56 +0000");
echo $wTime->format("d/m/Y H:i:s\n");
$wTime->add(new DateInterval("P810M")); 
echo $wTime->format("d/m/Y H:i:s");
```

The result is:

```
17/05/2011 01:54:56
17/11/2078 01:54:56
```

I can't see where I'm doing anything wrong. Is this a bug in the DateTime object, or is something off with my code? I've run into annoying bugs with it in the past. I am running the latest version of PHP (5.3.6) built from source on Mac OS X 10.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php), you're adding 810 months (~67 years). Try `PT810M`

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. I can't believe I made a post about such a stupid mistake. How shameful.

Comment: No worries. I'll admit the fact that PHP has `M` for both month and minutes is pretty lame. Looks like `I` is an alternative for minutes format. But from the docs, `T` is the *documented* way to specify `M` as minutes.

Answer (score 1):

`M` is for months, so this is adding 810 months (67.5 years). Use `i` or `I` for minutes.

```
$wTime->add(new DateInterval("P810I"));
```

The [PHP manual page for DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) has a complete list of the recognized formats.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually adding 810 months instead of minutes. Try -

```
$wTime->add(new DateInterval("P810I"));
```

Also looks like the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) is wrong. But if you look at the example output on that page, you will realise that the code for minutes is 'i', not 'm'.

Comment: Thanks. I can at least blame the PHP documentation partly for my stupidity :/

Answer (score 0):

You added months, not minutes. Try `i` instead of `m`